# Facebook share image sharethis

Tags: html, facebook, share, sharethis

In my site I add sharethis plugin to share pages

My problem is to manage the image in sharing page, and seems that facebook take the first image and not my image.

this is my page
http://www.netafim.com/testimonial/netafim-customers-video-testimonial---uvs-south-africa

In this page i have this meta tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.netafim.com/Data/Uploads/South Africa_sugarcane_share.png"/>
```

this is my image in the meta tag

[image: http://www.netafim.com/Data/Uploads/South%20Africa_sugarcane_share.png]

But when sharing i see another image

[[image]]

Why and how can i manage my sharing image?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***FIX:*** Rename the image filename without any whitespace characters(ie. ***space*** in filename)

So far, all it could ***scrape*** is just the title and description of it. And since it can't scrape the image(due to the space in the image filename), it has fallen back to the default image for your website, which is

[image: default]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, but change the image to file with no space does not resolve this problem. this is current image url http://www.netafim.com/Data/Uploads/South_Africa_sugarcane_share_1.png

Comment: As per [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), it still says error with your website's "og:image". It's either too small or too big to download...

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the name I can't see the image on the dialog page.

When I Share the page I see the image from the og:image tag.

But on the Dialog sometime the image exists and sometimes not.

1. some time its like this with no image
   [image]
2. and some times with the image
   [image]
   On the debugging page when click on the "see this in the share dialog" its seems good as expected

but when click from the site

i got "thin" version with no image. what can be the reason for the differant

[image]